# 32-bit or 16-bits elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, pohlig-hellman

I would like test vectors for 32-bit or 16-bits elliptic curves like 
$[p,
 a,
 b,
 G,
n, 
 h]$
, to test the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm in order to attack ECDLP over a finite prime field $F_p$.

Does anybody know a method to generate small $F_p$ parameters or can anybody supply the test vectors?

Comment: Hint: never start question with "I want".

Comment: I apologize I do not speak English well, it is not my native language i'm sorry and thanks for the remark :)

Comment: Do you need the curve's order to be smooth in order to test Pohlig-Hellman or would a prime order curve be ok ? It's unclear since you mentioned $n$ and $h$ which seems to me like you are looking for logarithms in the prime order subgroup...

Comment: First thank you sir for your answer, i would like to sign a message with ECDSA 16-bit or 32 bit (it's not standard).
But now I have encountered two problems, the first when $n$ is not a prime number (smooth number) I have the problem of the non-existence of the inverse modulo $n$, so I can not even sign and check my message. The second and I could sign the message with 8-bit ECDSA but with $n$ a prime number so I can not apply the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm.

Comment: @YIdir I understand the issue. I believe it would make more sense to test Pohlig-Hellman on a simple scalar multiplication (ECDH) than on ECDSA, because ECDSA needs to work in a prime order subgroup to invert the ephemeral key.

Comment: @Ruggero thanks, So I understand that I test this algorithm on ECDH because ECDSA requires that $n$ be a prime number ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example curve with smooth order $E/\mathbb{F}_p:y^2=x^3+ax+b$, generated with Magma.

\begin{align*}
p &= 2^{31}-1 \\
a &= 1456400922 \\
b &= 2005615003 \\
n &= 2^5\cdot 3^7 \cdot 5\cdot 17\cdot 19^2.
\end{align*}

I'd expect that if you are able to run PH, you should also be able to generate some test vectors yourself. The code is

```
p := 2^31-1;
Fp := GF(p);

repeat
    ct := 0;
    repeat
        a := Random(Fp);
        b := Random(Fp);
        D := 4*a^3+27*b^2;
    until D ne 0;
    E := EllipticCurve([Fp|a,b]);
    F := Factorization(#E);
    for f in F do
        if f[1] gt 25 then
            ct := 1;
        end if;
    end for;
until ct eq 0;
```

Comment: thanks sir, but i do not see the basic point $G$ ?

Comment: @YIdir Not trying to sound discouraging, but if you are implementing Pohlig-Hellman, then you should definitely be able to find some test vectors yourself. If you are not, you will probably have a bad time implementing this. For example, what do you mean by *the* basic point $G$?

Comment: Note to anyone tempted to use these parameters: they are much too small to give any security. Finding the private key from the public key is trivial.