# 16 or 32 bit Digital Signature for Hardware Level

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, signature

I am working on a hardware security problem. It involves authentication of contents of a packet header at the network-on-chip level, which is very resource constrained in nature. I have a Pearson Hash of the header contents, which I would like to digitally sign so that it can be verified by other nodes of the network that the hash was indeed generated by the source node. The hash is of 8 bits. I want to know what digital signature schemes can be used to generate a small signature of 16-32 bits only. I have a maximum of 64 bits free space in the header.

Note that, since this signature is at a hardware level network, it is not a constraint that it should be unbreakable or extremely tough. Any signature which is strong enough to not be broken within few nanoseconds at hardware level is fine for my application which is time critical.

I studied the answer in [32-bit or 16-bits elliptic curves](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/45053/32-bit-or-16-bits-elliptic-curves), and I tried to understand the ECDSA implementation of 32-bit but I couldn't. I am new to this, and still struggling with knowing how to generate curves and fix the constants to be used. I'd be happy to know more about this too.

Any help or clues would be highly appreciated.

Thank you :)